# The two Collatz-maps associated to characters modulo 8

Tags: nt.number-theory, recreational-mathematics, collatz-conjecture

Given a Dirichlet character $\chi$ modulo $8$ we consider the map $\mu(x)=x/2$ if $x$ is even and $\mu(x)=(3x+\chi(x))/2$ otherwise.
(The corresponding map for $\chi$ the trivial Dirichlet character modulo $2$ is therefore the map of the Collatz-conjecture.)

The two Dirichlet characters modulo $8$ have seemingly very different orbits under iteration:

For $\chi(1,3,5,7)=(1,-1,-1,1)$ the behaviour seems to be
as for the Collatz-map: Every orbit starting at $n<10^6$
ends in the period $(1,2)$.

For $\chi(1,3,5,7)=(1,1,-1,-1)$, there are seemingly plenty of diverging orbits and at least four periodic orbits given by
$$(1,2)$$
$$(5,7,10)$$
$$(13,19,29,43,65,98,49,74,37,55,82,41,62,31,46,23,34,17,26)$$
$$(53,79,118,59,89,137,67,101,151,226,170,85,127,190,95),142,71,106)$$
Seemingly diverging orbits start at $51$ and $83$ (there are probably many others). Seemingly only finitely many odd numbers have preperiodic orbits.

These different behaviours are not completely unexpected:

$\chi(1,3,5,7)=(1,-1,-1,1)$ corresponds roughly to multiplication by $3/4,\leq 3/8,3/2,3/4$ on odd classes modulo $8$. Since the product
of these four numbers is $\leq 81/128<1$, the associated map should be roughly contracting.

$\chi(1,3,5,7)=(1,1,-1,-1)$ on the other hand leads roughly to multiplications by $3/4,3/2,3/2,3/2$ with product $81/32>1$
indicating an expanding behaviour under iteration. (The situation
is even slightly worse: An analysis of the underlying non-deterministic automaton with states $1,3,5,7$ modulo $8$ shows that
the frequency in orbits of odd numbers congruent to $3$ or $7$ modulo $8$ should roughly be 50 percent larger than the frequency of odd numbers congruent to $1$ or $5$.)

*Any ideas for rigorous proofs?*

(Remark: The corresponding map for the unique Dirichlet character modulo $4$ given by $\chi(1,3)=(1,-1)$ is easy to analyze.)